# Count how many rows have between a specific value / feature

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

[image]

I want the count to reset when it sees "LOAN_CASH_IN"

Still trying with window, but can't find the solution.

```
select aux.*, count(1) over (partition by wallet_id
                      order by order_created_at asc)
from aux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use two levels of window functions:

```
select aux.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by wallet_id, grp
                          order by order_created_at asc
                         )
from (select aux.*,
             sum(case when order_type_micro = 'LOAN_CASH_IN' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by wallet_id order by order_created_at) grp
      from aux
     ) aux;
```

`row_number()` is more appropriate for what you want unless you really, really understand why you are using `count()` as a cumulative window function.

Comment: funny, you replied the "hidden" question I had. Actually I wanted to make a mean of trasactions an user make before requesting a loan. I was using count() because my intention was to aggregate.